# changes to java program not being reflected

Tags: java, linux, unix, classpath

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "Some Programme v1.0.0"
JAVA_HOME=/apps/clear/jdk1.7.0_45
PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${JAVA_HOME}/lib:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:.:

export NEWAPI_DIR=/local/newapi/1.1.1.1.2
LIBRARY_PATH=$NEWAPI_DIR/Linux-2.6/lib
MY_HOME=/home/clear/dev/app/lse
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:$LIBRARY_PATH
MY_CLASSPATH=${MY_HOME}/lib/yt500.jar:${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/rt.jar:${MY_HOME}/lib/ftlse.jar:$LIBRARY_PATH/JNewApi.jar:$LIBRARY_PATH/Jfib.jar
date
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -classpath $MY_CLASSPATH com.company.ft.lse.LseParser /home/clear/dev/app/lse/config/config.xml
date
```

The above is my run script. I have an application `LseParser.java` to which I have changed the code. But this code is not reflected when I have run the code (. ./run) in unix box. When I locate the `ftlse.jar` within where the `LseParser.class` exists, it is last date modified some long time ago. Can someone please point me what i'm doing wrong or suggest any checks or alterations I should make ? am i missing any lines in my script i should have ?

Comment: How are you compiling the code and building the jar file?

Comment: i'm not sure, i just do . ./run and see class compiling but with old one. what file can i check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is a [compiled language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language). You need to run the [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html) compiler first and then the [jar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/) command to create the jar file. You can use the tutorials I linked to to figure out how to run them correctly for your project. Once you have your compile and package commands you can add them to your run script. However, I strongly recommend you look into a build automation tool such as [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/index.html) so that you don't have to work with custom built run scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed export before JAVA_HOME in 3rd line... so the shell, instead of taking $JAVA_HOME it as a variable, interpret it as a command.